# Crontab not working - cronjobs

Tags: cron, raspberrypi

thank you all in advanced. Getting some issues with raspberry pi b with crontab

My sh script is to create a movie in a folder using images inside a specific folder.

```
*/5 * * * * sh /bin/script.sh
```

As you can see i've uploaded the script inside bin and i need it to run every 5 minutes

inside my sh i have this;

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo "Hey there, this is the timelapse script lets see if its running"
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i /home/pi/11/april2020/'*.jpg' -q:a 3 -s 1920x1080 -c:v wmv1 /home/pi/11/april2020/output/video.wmv
```

When i do service cron status this is what i am getting

```
    Jan 01 15:20:01 raspberrypi CRON[20036]: (pi) CMD (sh /bin/timelapse.sh)
Jan 01 15:20:02 raspberrypi cron[19982]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jan 01 15:20:02 raspberrypi postfix/sendmail[20040]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jan 01 15:20:03 raspberrypi CRON[20035]: (pi) MAIL (mailed 28980 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA
                                         )
Jan 01 15:20:03 raspberrypi CRON[20035]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi
Jan 01 15:25:01 raspberrypi CRON[20059]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jan 01 15:25:01 raspberrypi CRON[20060]: (pi) CMD (sh /bin/timelapse.sh)
Jan 01 15:25:02 raspberrypi cron[19982]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jan 01 15:25:02 raspberrypi CRON[20059]: (pi) MAIL (mailed 28980 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA)
Jan 01 15:25:02 raspberrypi CRON[20059]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi
```

Please help i am stuck with this i cannot understand why it wouldnt work.

Comment: `/path/to/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` (skip `sh`) should disable email alert, next you need to look into your mail configuration, you seem to miss a file.

Comment: Thank you. I do not need email to be sent - although it could be a good thing on a later stage. I will try that now.

Comment: @bac0n you're a diamond!!! Thank you so much. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Your shebang says `bash`, you run it with `sh`... pick one and stick to it.